# Lerp for lighting brightness is not gradually increasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

My implementation of Lerp should gradually increase the light from `minbrightness` to `maxBrightness` over time. It does change the range of my light however it is immediately going to my `maxBrightness` instead of gradually increasing. Where have I gone wrong?

**Here is the code I am using**

```
private void Update()
{
    //this is a timer that will only only count down when collided = true
    if (_collided == true)
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        _light1.range = Mathf.Lerp(minbrightness, maxBrightness, lightTimer);
        //increases interloper
        lightTimer += _brightenRate * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        //this sets the lights range value to be bigger then normal
        _light1.range = Mathf.Lerp(maxBrightness, minbrightness, lightTimer);
        //increases interloper
        lightTimer += _brightenRate * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    //checks if the time value is 0
    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        //this resets the value back
        timeLeft = timeLeftReset;
        _collided = false;
    }
}
```

I have heard of `IEnumerator`, but am unsure of how to apply it to my current solution or if that will even fix my current problem.

Comment: Looks fine to me. your value for `_brightenRate` is probably too large. If it's a serialized field (if you use `[SerializeField]` and/or `public`) make sure you are setting it in the inspector if you aren't setting it somewhere in code.

Comment: @Ruzihm _brightenRate is 0.5f